# Does WordPress function get_post(post_id) query the database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In my WordPress theme the theme author first makes a database query to get all active posts to get post IDs like this:

```
$SQL = "SELECT post_id FROM mytable_postmeta 
            WHERE meta_key = 'expiry_date' AND CAST(meta_value AS DATETIME) >='2023-01-14 12:00:00'"
$posts_found = $wpdb->get_results($SQL, OBJECT);
```

Then he later loops over the results and get each posts by it's ID like this:

```
foreach($posts_found as $single_post){   
    global $post;
    $post = get_post($single_post->ID);                                              
}
```

My question is if this is a database query to get all post IDs and then one database query for each post in the foreach loop? I.e., does the get_post WordPress function query the database once per post in the loop?

If so, can I re-write this in a smart way to reduce the number of database calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is, try this:

```php
$SQL = "SELECT post_id FROM mytable_postmeta 
            WHERE meta_key = 'expiry_date' AND CAST(meta_value AS DATETIME) >='2023-01-14 12:00:00'";

$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col($SQL);
$posts = get_posts([
    'include' => $post_ids,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
]);
```

or even better, using `meta_query`

```php
$posts = get_posts([
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'expiry_date',
            'value' => '2023-01-14 12:00:00',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATETIME'
        ]
    ],
    'post_status' => 'publish'
]);
```

Yes, `get_post` does perform an additional query each time it is called.

Comment: get_posts would be an improvement since I only need to make 2 database calls. Would it even be possible to send all information with get_posts and not do the first query?

Comment: For some reason this returns 0, my original query returns 18 since I have 18 active posts

Comment: Add `'debug' => true` under `post_status`. You should be able to deduce the issue from there and make the appropriate fixes, something in the query may be off such as the date format or type, it's been some time.

Comment: Not sure what that does, it doesn't write anything to console nor do I get any other info

Comment: How about `var_dump($wpdb->last_query)` after the call?

Comment: It works after a few tweaks to fit my own database :)